# grails validation errors don't show up in view

Tags: grails

I confirm that the errors on on the object before I send them to the view

```
   trip.riders.each{rider->
       rider.errors.each{it->
            //visually confirming to myself the errors are there
            println it;
       }
   }
   render(view:'edit',model:[trip:trip);
   return;
```

The error I am confirming prints to console "Field error in object on field 'mileage'...."

Yet when rendered

```
<g:each in="${trip?.riders}" var="rdr" status='i'>
    <div class='form-category'>
        <div class='error'>
             <g:hasErrors bean="${rdr}" field="mileage">
                 <g:renderErrors bean="${rdr}" field="mileage" as="list" />
            </g:hasErrors>
```

No errors show up. What could be happening here?

*UPDATE*

I believe the problem is along these lines...
http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/grails/97568-haserrors-true-disappears
Seems hibernate persists things in some instances in a way that causes validation errors to be cleared.

Comment: what grails version do you use?

Comment: We have a legacy system 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<g:hasErrors>
    <g:eachError> ${it} </g:eachError>
</g:hasErrors>
```

If you have added custom errors using "rejectValue()" method, validate() or save() method will remove custom errors added to the domain instance